# Can I use filemtime('style.css') in PHP to force a browser to reload a css?

Tags: php, css, caching, browser-cache

Can I use filemtime in PHP to force a browser to reload a css?

```
 $mtime = filemtime('style.css');
 echo "\style.css?mod=" . $mtime;
```

Is filemtime too slow?

Comment: I was looking at using `filemtime()` as part of a browser cache busting technique for css/js/image files and was considering whether caching the `mtime` using `memcached` would be beneficial to prevent multiple file system calls.

1000 `filemtime()` calls (including clearing the stat cache between calls) vs. 1000 `memcached` reads. `filemtime()` is significantly faster.

1000 `filemtime()` took: 0.004787
1000 `memcache` took: 0.075099

Comment: doesn't have to be mtime. just a DIFFERENT value than what was used previously, so the browser will see a "new" url and force a load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filemtime` should be fine *under normal circumstances*.

You could also look into E-Tags and just have Apache do the work for you.

Comment: `filemtime` returns timestamp, which is increased every second.

Comment: Apache has E-Tags enabled by default (I see E-tag in response header), but when I update my stylesheet usually the browser load it from cache instead of server. I think that use a param in the link is a strong method to force the browser to avoid cache. My problem is how calculate it avoiding overload.

Comment: @Yossarian nope. You are mistaken with time(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: On an SSD based server with operating system file system caching for frequently accessed resources, the overhead for `filemtime` is likely to be very low, at least for smaller sites, though this is only anecdotal based on a site experiencing ~1,000 page views a day. The small amount of time spent accessing file modification times is made up in spades by other website caching mechanisms.